# Invalid address when startup gunicorn

Tags: django, nginx, gunicorn

I encounterd an error when bound gunicorn listen address to my nginx server,here is the thing:

**1.gunicorn_wsgi.py**

```
import multiprocessing

bind="192.168.239.145:8080"(my nginx server ip address)

workers = multiprocessing.cpu_count()  2 + 1
```

**2.nginx.conf**

```
http{
     upstream realservers{
       server 192.168.239.146:8080;(my django and gunicorn address)
     }
     servr{
         listen 80;
         server_name example.com
         location / {
              proxy_pass http://realservers
         }
     }
}
```

when i ran `gunicorn -c gunicorn-wsgi.py myproject.wsgi`,error occur:

```
[2015-03-30 04:56:05 -0700] [38656] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.3.0
[2015-03-30 04:56:05 -0700] [38656] [ERROR] Invalid address: ('192.168.239.145', 8080)
```

I noticed that **[gunicorn](http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/latest/deploy.html#nginx-configuration)**  has mentioned that if you are running nginx on a different host than gunicorn you need to tell gunicorn to trust the the x-forward-* headers sent by nginx.

> If you are running Nginx on a different host than Gunicorn you need to
>   tell Gunicorn to trust the X-Forwarded-* headers sent by Nginx. By
>   default, Gunicorn will only trust these headers if the connection
>   comes from localhost. This is to prevent a malicious client from
>   forging these headers:

```
gunicorn -w 3 --forwarded-allow-ips="10.170.3.217,10.170.3.220" test:app
```

I followed what it said ,but still same error. And I change the address to 127.0.0.1 and 0.0.0.0 ,they work fine,but is not secure,How to configure it ,please help me !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's obviously not your problem, but it is confusing that you're calling your configuration file "gunicon_wsgi.py". It's not your WSGI file. Call it "gunicorn_conf.py" or something similar.

Your problem is however that you have misunderstood what it means to bind to an IP address. You can't bind your gunicorn server to an IP address on a different machine; that makes no sense at all. And it's not "insecure" to bind to 0.0.0.0.

Comment: The configuration file name is arbitrary,gunicorn can specify the configuration file using gunicorn --config command line,,as you point out,i change gunicorn listening address to 127.0.0.1 and configure the x-forwarded-* header to my nginx server address,but still not work.

Comment: Yes but don't call it a WSGI file when it isn't, that's unnecessarily confusing. And there's no point binding to 127.0.0.1 if your nginx is forwarding from a different machine: you need to bind either to *all* addresses (0.0.0.00) or the address gunicorn is actually listening on (192.168.239.146).

Comment: wow,forgive me, i am too careless,now it worked well,anyway,thanks for ur help :）and shame on me!!!